# Probability that two people see eachother TWICE during the day.

Tags: probability

If two people each go to the coffee shop at random times between 12 am and 12 pm, and they each stay for 3 hours, what is the probability they see eachother?

That problem is a classic and its a simple excercise in geometric probability. I came up with a variant which seems much harder to solve, at least with the geometric approach:

If two people each go to the coffee shop TWICE at random times between 12 am and 12 pm, and they stay for 1 hour each time, what is the probability they see eachother? To be clear, each person goes to the coffee shop at some time, stays for an hour, leaves, comes back at a later time, and stays again for an hour, then leaves again. Note that this does not exclude the possibility of a person staying for 2 contiguous hours at the coffee shop.

Comment: I would be impressed if we can solve this with geometric probability. The problem is I can't visualize the region of interest, and I'm not sure if we can do it in two dimensions or if three dimensions is required.

Comment: The location of the points $a,b$ of beginnings of the two one-hour stays satisfy $0 \le a < a+1 \le b < b+1 \le 12.$ Inside a 12 by 12 box (with $a$ on the horizontal and $b$ on the vertical) the points $(a,b)$ then lie in a triangle bounded on the right by $a=10$ and above by $b=11,$ and below by a slanted side $b=a+1.$ Then there would be yet another diagram of this type for the times $c,d$ for the other person. So I think you have really a four dimensional "region", and it seems it may be difficult to express the event that they meet.

Comment: One more thing: They each go for two one-hour stretches. Do you want them to meet twice, or just at least once?

Comment: The latter, but as a bonus you can calculate both.

Comment: I feared that it would be 4 dimensional. But even if we can't visualize it, we can maybe use the fact that we know the areas of the projection into lower dimensions?

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas on this?